# What can cause washing machine to clean improperly

Tags: washing-machine

The washing machine (Whirlpool AWO/C 6104, about  years old) seems to work well (pumps water in, heats, spins in both directions, detergent is washed out completely, drains... all you could expect).
No errors displayd, cycle completes, no unexpected noises.
When the was not really dirty to begin with all is fine.
When, however, the clothes is dirty (food stains, mud, blood, grease, ...) the stains remain unchanged.
This is far from fully loaded, same detergent that would reliably wash given stains in other washing machines.
What could be the problem?
Is it possible that the machine is so badly designed that it is just incapable of washig well?
It does all the steps, just the steps do not lead to expected results.

Comment: Is this a recent change? Your post seems to indicate it's always been like this.

Comment: How do you know another machine will reliably wash these stains out? Have you done comparison tests with equally soiled garments some washed in your machine, some washed in your neighbors' machine? I know our clothes take pre-treatment for heavy food stains, blood, and grease if there's _any_ hope of getting those out.

Comment: talk to the manufacturer tech support

Comment: @Tetsujin Hard to tell, before children there were rarely any real stains or dirt so no problem to be seen, now it got visible.

Comment: @FreeMan not a rigorous test - that is planned, but yes stains untouched by our washing machine were cleaned perfectly by other washing machines we got accesss to (family, holidays).

Answer (score 2):

> the clothes is dirty (food stains, mud, blood, grease, ...)

All of the types of stains you listed are often difficult to get out, even by hand.  Different soaps and detergents are better at cleaning certain stains than others. A washing machine isn't going to clean dried blood, even with the best pretreating and scrubbing you may not get it out.  Tomato sauces can also be hard to get out.

Grease usually requires the right cleaning solution and ideally treated before going in the washer.  For instance if I get automotive grease on my hands, I can use all the hand soap I want, it isn't coming off.  I go for something like Fast Orange (or a degreaser) with a scrub brush for my hands, and I treat grease stains on clothes the same way.

The sooner you address the stain, the easier it will be to get out.  If you just put it in the laundry basket and run it through the washer a week later, the stain has had a week to set into the fabric.  Identify what caused the stain, and find the right treatment early will give you the best success at getting stains out.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, unfortunately these do not cover why one machine does worse job than other machines...